# Undoing Clipboard Text with NSManager

Tags: ios, ios6, nsundomanager, uipasteboard

I'm implementing NSUndoManager with a UITextView control.  If I want to undo the last text change, I can do it with

```
// NSUndoManager *myUndoManager;  Declared in the header

if (myUndoManager.canUndo) {
    [myUndoManager undo];
}
```

That's quite simple.  If I, however, insert the clipboard text to the TextView control like the following, myUndoManager.canUndo is empty.

```
textview1.text = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];
```

Is it possible for me to undo text changes when the clipboard text is used?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just need to add text to the stack manually.

```
- (IBAction)goClicked1:(id)sender {
    NSString *pastetext = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];
    [self setText:pastetext];
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)str {
    NSUndoManager *undoManager = [self undoManager];
    NSString *oldtext = textview1.text;
    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setText:oldtext];
    textview1.text = str;
}
```